# How do i push compressed CT files in remote dicom server?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I use DcmSnd tool for pushing compressed CT files in remote Dicom server.The problem is while retriving uncompressed files from same Server using DcmQr I get all files but in form of images and it gives me failure status for all files.

```
10:27:00,357 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-1] 1:C_FIND_RSP with Dataset
class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
status: ff01
```

And After that it start decompression of all files

```
10:27:01,692 INFO  [FsmImpl] received A-RELEASE-RQ
10:27:01,692 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending A-RELEASE-RP
10:27:01,693 INFO  [ServerImpl] handle - Socket[addr=/192.168.1.121,port=54491,localport=11112]
10:27:01,695 INFO  [FsmImpl] Socket[addr=/192.168.1.121,port=54491,localport=11112]
10:27:01,696 INFO  [FsmImpl] received AAssociateRQ
    appCtxName: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
    implClass:  1.2.40.0.13.1.1
    implVersion:    dcm4che-2.0
    calledAET:  DCM4CHEE
    callingAET: DCM4CHEE
    maxPDULen:  16384
    asyncOpsWindow: maxOpsInvoked=1, maxOpsPerformed=0
    pc-1:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
    pc-3:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.3/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
    pc-5:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2/CT Image Storage
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
    pc-7:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
    pc-9:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.3/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
    pc-11:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2/CT Image Storage
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
    RoleSelection[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2/CT Image Storage, scu=false, scp=true]
    ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
    ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.3/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET, info=00]
10:27:01,696 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending AAssociateAC
    appCtxName: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
    implClass:  1.2.40.0.13.1.1.1
    implVersion:    dcm4che-1.4.34
    calledAET:  DCM4CHEE
    callingAET: DCM4CHEE
    maxPDULen:  16352
    asyncOpsWindow: maxOpsInvoked=1, maxOpsPerformed=1
    pc-1:   0 - acceptance
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
    pc-3:   0 - acceptance
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
    pc-5:   0 - acceptance
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
    pc-7:   4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
    pc-9:   4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
    pc-11:  0 - acceptance
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
    RoleSelection[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2/CT Image Storage, scu=false, scp=true]
    ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
    ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.3/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET, info=00]
10:27:01,698 INFO  [FsmImpl] received [pc-3] 1:C_GET_RQ with Dataset
    class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.3/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET
10:27:01,708 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-11] 2:C_STORE_RQ with Dataset
    class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2/CT Image Storage
    inst:   1.2.840.113704.1.111.6168.1127829523.11762/?
10:27:01,708 INFO  [FileDataSource] M-READ file:/media/data1/DicomServer2/dcm4chee-2.18.0-mysql/server/default/archive/2014/10/7/10/F4620895/47D29C4B/631BA185
10:27:01,736 INFO  [CodecCmd] start decompression of image: 512x512x1 (current codec tasks: compress&decompress:1 decompress:1)
10:27:01,742 INFO  [FsmImpl] closing connection - Socket[addr=/192.168.1.121,port=57544,localport=11112]
10:27:01,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] finished - Socket[addr=/192.168.1.121,port=57544,localport=11112]
10:27:01,779 INFO  [CodecCmd] finished decompression in 42ms. (remaining codec tasks: compress&decompress:0 decompress:0)
10:27:01,789 INFO  [FsmImpl] received [pc-11] 2:C_STORE_RSP
    status: 0
10:27:01,840 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-3] 1:C_GET_RSP
    class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.3/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET
    status: 0
```

Is DcmSnd tool I am using for pushing files to remote dicom Server is proper for compresed files?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about DcmSnd, but you could give a try to [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/), that supports sending compressed files through the DICOM protocol (i.e. it supports the JPEG/JPEG2k transfer syntaxes for C-Store SCU).

Answer (score 0):

According to above log, the presentation context “5” and “11” of your Associate request only contains uncompressed transfer syntaxes for CT Image Storage. Sever is accepting what you proposed and sending the data in agreed upon transfer syntax using presentation context “11” (which is Explicite VR Little Endian). Try adding an additional presentation context for CT Image Storage abstract syntax with compressed transfer syntax to your associate request command.